# Impossible Open two modals with Kendo jquery

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I am adding new functionality to an old system that use Kendo UI (2013 version) with jquery 1.9.1.

I have to do the following. When I click an icon this open the first modal that contains a button, and if I click this button this should open another open without close the first one, like this:

[image]

The problem that I have is when the second modal is opened, this overrides the content of the first one.

So I have two functions, the function A open the first modal with the template defined in options and the function B receives another template and this I need to open in other modal like a picture.

```
a: function(options, e){
    $("#some-id").kendoIGDialog({
        template: options.template,
    }).data('kendoIGDialog').open();
},

b: function(options, e){
    $("#another-id").kendoIGDialog({
        template: options.template,
    }).data('kendoIGDialog').open();
}
```

Comment: Is the `options` object different in the two instances?

Comment: Yes, and there are 2 different templates

Comment: its possible your modal id is the same if you are using ints.